# Is it correct to say, "The specimen was observed using a microscope."

Tags: passive-voice, participles

In scientific journals, we often find passive sentences like "The specimen was observed using a microscope" and "The specimen was observed by using a microscope." Are they correct?

If we use active sentences, it would be simple and easy like "We observed the specimen with a microscope." or "We observed the specimen using a microscope."

Comment: What makes you think they might not be correct?

Comment: The first one, "The specimen was observed using a microscope" could be ambigous, as is "I saw the man with a telescope."

Comment: [_under_ a microscope](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=observed+under+a+microscope%2C+observed+through+a+microscope%2C+observed+using+a+microscope&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobserved%20under%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobserved%20through%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobserved%20using%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cobserved%20under%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobserved%20through%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobserved%20using%20a%20microscope%3B%2Cc0) is more common

Comment: "The specimen was observed using a microscope" would likely provoke a few laughs, from certain individual (such as myself).

Comment: I think the sentence is not correct because the subject of the sentence is "specimen" and "specimen" cannot use a microscope.

Answer (score 0):

Passive is used in such statements to avoid the need to use "I" or "we".  In some contexts (such as scholarly articles) it's considered poor form to for the authors to refer to themselves, except when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Interestingly the same does not apply to mathematics papers, where you often see the sentence form along the lines of "We now integrate this expression with respect to $x$, and substitute $\sin t$ for $y$ ..."

Comment: @PrimeMover - I wonder if that usage isn't a sort of "royal" or "editorial" "we".

Comment: It's always seemed to me like the teacher-pupil "we", which means, "Let's perform this exercise together, children." At least, that's how I understand it when I use it.

Answer (score -2):

The reason for the use of the passive voice is because the topic of the paragraph is most likely to be the "specimen" here. This concept may often be overlooked in English, but is widely taught in general language classes in many other languages.

It would be unnatural to use the active voice version if the rest the paragraph was written with the specimen as the topic.

"The virus sample had two DNA strands alongside the nucleus. It was green in color. We observed the specimen using a microscope. It was considered a small virus. It's DNA was very unique".

Notice how the active voice sentence doesn't fit in my crude example above.

Hence you should use the passive voice.

Comment: "Very unique" is a solecism. A thing is either unique (a one-of-a-kind) or it is not. You can't have degrees of uniqueness.

Comment: @PrimeMover ... my dictionary has a long note about this alleged prohibition, saying "language is more complex than this"

Comment: @GEdgar Weasel words for "some people are too stupid to be trusted with vocal cords".

Comment: I don't think it works like that. Let's take an SF paragraph that I just made up. "The nasty mutant virus landed on earth. It ran amuck causing people to swear in Latin. It even made women it infected favor gladiators and men named 'Cicero'. "The mutant virus is the prime subject here. Passive voice is not required.